# loading a javascript on a WP PAGE

Tags: pages, javascript

so im trying to do this *http://jsfiddle.net/2XV7w/5/* on `my custom_page` on wordpress.
this is a conditional html form. It will display a specific `<div>` when i choose a specific drop-down value.

when i try to load a sample javascript on my `custom_page.php` it works fine. to make sure that JS is working.

```
<script>
document.write("<p>javasript test</p>");
</script>
```

but when i use this `script.js`, it wouldn't work.

```
$("#dd").change(function(){
var selected= $("#dd option:selected").text();
$('div').hide(); 
$('#'+ selected).show(); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').hide();
});
```

My custom_page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>

<!-- DROPDOWN -->
<select id="dd">
<option value="1">SHOW DIV 1</option>
<option value="1">SHOW DIV 2</option>
</select>

 <!-- DIV CONTENT -->
<div id="1">Content of div 1</div>
<div id="2">Content of div 2</div>

<!-- FORM -->
<form action="" method="POST">
    Message <input type="text" name="message" /> &nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: This is not how you load js in wordpress. Try to [register then enqueue the script](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/)

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a file called `functions.php` in your theme folder. Open it and add the following snippet:

```
function wpse_109027_enqueue_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_109027_enqueue_js' );
```

[`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) is used to add javascript files. The `array('jquery')` part means that WordPress should load jQuery before loading your javascript file.

Note that WordPress loads jQuery in [NoConclict Mode](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/). You should therefore use [jQuery noConflict Wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) in your code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#dd").change(function(){
    var selected= $("#dd option:selected").text();
    $('div').hide(); 
    $('#'+ selected).show(); 
  });

    $('div').hide();
});
```